# Desfazer um voto

Tags: debate

Pq não posso desfazer um voto que tinha dado anteriormente?

Por exemplo, nessa questão ([Como vetorizar código em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239440/como-vetorizar-c%c3%b3digo-em-c)) eu dei um voto positivo na primeira leitura rápida que tinha feito.

Agora que dei uma olhada com mais calma, percebi que não é uma questão boa assim. Na verdade não dá para entender o que tá perguntando já que, ao meu ver, os compiladores já fazem o que ele está pedindo. Sendo assim, gostaria de remover o meu voto positivo até que a questão fosse esclarecida e, aí sim, daria o voto positivo se achasse que vale a pena.

Então, a pergunta é bem simples: **Pq não posso fazer isso?**

Ou seja, a pergunta é sobre a sistemática de como o voto é tratado pelo sistema.

Note que não estou pedindo uma aula sobre como votar, ou como devo analisar a questão para poder proferir um voto sobre a mesma. Qualquer reposta nesse sentido indica que o respondente não entendeu a pergunta ainda.

Comment: Se o post não está claro o suficiente, pra que votar positivo? Isso é muito incoerente.

Comment: Pq quando li a primeira vez, me pareceu coerente e bom, mas quando vc para para pensar com carinho e analisa o que está acontecendo, vê que não é exatamente isso, que tem problemas e seria legal resolver. O arrependimento incentivaria isso, a correção do post

Comment: Então porque não *"parar para pensar com carinho e analisa o que está acontecendo"* antes de votar? O objetivo do voto é justamente indicar qualidade do post. Muitos usuários, por vezes, parecem tratar o sistema como se fossem likes. Voto é algo pra avaliar qualidade, por isso, deveria ser dado após uma avaliação razoavelmente cuidadosa daquilo em que se está votando. Eu nao voto em nada que faço leitura rapida, mas costumo favoritar para ler com mais tempo depois e ai sim, votar positivamente. As vezes até comentar parabenizando o autor pra incentivá-lo.

Comment: É exatamente por isso que estou perguntando. Pq me pareceu uma boa pergunta. Só que me arrependi. Não é um _like_ é uma mudança de opinião, que por sinal ocorre raramente, mas acontece. E é exatamente a ideia de retirar o voto, qualidade do _post_. Se não posso fazer isso, então o _post_ está numa qualidade artificial

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista e respeito, claro, apesar de discordar. Quanto aos likes, me referi ao que observo desde que entrei no site, peço desculpas se soou como uma acusação de que o comportamento é seu, não foi a intenção.

Comment: Se o autor da postagem que você votou editar e postar algo que vc discorde tenho quase certeza que você poderá desfazer o voto, o mesmo vale para downvotes, se você deu um downvote o autor da postagem melhorou o conteudo e você acha que o downvote não é mais necessário você pode desfazer.

Answer (score 14):

Se os votos pudessem ser desfeitos a qualquer momento, eles perderiam peso. O voto é um compromisso, então melhor ler a postagem com atenção antes de votar. Se a postagem for editada após o voto, aí sim o sistema te dá a chance de reverter – afinal o conteúdo da postagem não é mais o mesmo.

O sistema te dá 5 minutos pra mudar de ideia e retirar um voto. Depois disso, só se houver uma edição. Agora, arrependimento sobre votos não devia ser motivo de grandes preocupações. Eu já me arrependi de vários votos, positivos e negativos, que o sistema não me deixou reverter. Paciência. Acho que se se pudesse mudar um voto a qualquer momento, as pontuações seriam muito voláteis e isso teria um impacto negativo na comunidade.

Answer (score 6):

> como os comentários se foram, comentários são descartáveis, vou formalizar como resposta

Assim como o [@Articuno](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6366/desfazer-um-voto#comment24584_6366) citou no comentário dele e eu conversei contigo, penso eu que votos devem avaliar o conteúdo em si, não basta algo "parecer legal" ou "parecer útil", se você está decidido a voltar atrás no seu upvote isto é um sinal claro de que o seu julgamento sobre a postagem foi precipitado ou mal avaliado.

Não entenda mal, não estou lhe "julgando" necessariamente, estou querendo que você você faça as seguintes perguntas a si mesmo:

- Eu tenho entendimento o suficiente para votar nesta postagem?
- Isso me será útil?

Se você entende o suficiente (mesmo que minimo, mas tem noção) então creio que pode avaliar e então pense em **algo útil** pra ti como algo sendo útil aos outros, sendo assim creio que provavelmente vale sim um upvote.

Agora se você quer voltar atrás, deve ter um motivo, se a pergunta não foi editada e o motivo foi algo que você só percebeu depois até entendo querer desfazer, mas pergunte a si mesmo, a pergunta é útil?

### Vote no conteúdo

Então a partir deste ponto é seu ponto de vista, mas quero deixar uma coisa claro, não só pra ti, mas pra qualquer um que ler:

Não votem pelas pessoas, votem pela qualidade e utilidade do conteúdo, teu voto representa muito pra comunidade e influencia muito, pessoalmente eu penso que:

- Não é porque o cara é legal que a postagem merece voto
- Não é porque o cara é um chato que merece downvote
- Não porque algo "parece legal" ou "parece útil" que merece upvote

Nós temos que avaliar o conteúdo da postagem e não os autores, por empatia ou antipatia e no momento de avaliar o conteúdo devemos ter a responsabilidade e ter o minimo de certeza se realmente aquilo é útil de alguma forma.

---

### Falando sobre a pergunta espefica

Apenas para salientar, eu li essa pergunta no momento que o autor a publicou [Como vetorizar código em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239440/3635), eu não dei upvote e nem downvote, pelo simples motivo que fiquei um pouco incerto pois a pergunta é confusa no final:

> Quando eu uso a flag de vetorização para ver quantos loops estão sendo vetorizado com a ajuda da -O2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized ele me responde " loop vetorized " ou seja somente um loop foi vetorizado e se eu usar a -all em vez da -optimized ele me retorna que muitas partes do programa não foi vetorizado.

O problema dele todo é com o entendimento do texto que esta no singular e não no plural, mas ele não mostra o resultado, você mesmo notou isto depois:

> [Não entendi a sua pergunta. Veja no coliru Tem 2 loops vetorizados – Amadeus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239440/como-vetorizar-c%C3%B3digo-em-c#comment490548_239440)

Eu fiquei na duvida quanto ao texto e presumo que você entende sobre o assunto, mas efetuou o teste só depois de votar, então minha dica é, se você domina o assunto e pode testar, então cabe a você por o pé no freio antes de votar e fazer os testes e então sim determinar se o upvote ali será útil.

Então repito novamente, você tem um poder e deve usar com responsabilidade

[image: seja um herói]